# Access specifier triggers error TS7008: Build:Member 'public' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript

I'm building node module using typescript 3.1 on VS2017 15.9. The following snippet fails to compile:

```
export class
t_Foo
{
    public
    Bar(/* no arguments accepted */) /* no value returned */
    {
        /* no op */
        return;
    }
}; // t_Foo
```

Is there something wrong with this code? It seems that `public` access specifier is treated as class member for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Typescirpt interprets the `public Bar() {...}` definition as `public; Bar() {...}`.

This is beacuse of the newline. Like javascript, Typescript does not force you to use `;`. This unfortuntely leads to ambiguities, and you just hit one of them.

The erorr you are getting is due to the fact that since TS sees your definition as `public; Bar() {...}`, `public`  will be a field without a type annotation (and hence the error) and `Bar` will be a public method (since the default modifier is public in typescript).

Comment: [Isn't `public` a keyword](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/fad889283e710ee947e8412e173d2c050107a3c1/src/compiler/scanner.ts#L80) that can not be treated as an identifier, just like other keywords?

Comment: @VTT it is a keyword but it's not forbidden as a class field name